# How to get Pipe and Here String in Python?

Tags: python, bash, pipe, stdin, herestring

When calling a Python script via

```bash
echo foobar | python myscript.py <<< test123
```

How can I get both strings (the "foobar" and "test123") in the Python script?

When trying

```py
import sys
import select

r, w, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
if r:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    print("Line: " + line)
```

the script only returns "test123" if called as `echo foobar | python myscript.py <<< test123`.

If called via `echo foobar | python myscript.py` the "foobar" is returned.

If called via `python myscript.py <<< test123` also "test123" is returned.

But how can I get both strings?

Comment: I don't think you can get `foobar` but maybe you're wanting to pass `foobar` to your script? You can use `python myscript.py -foobar 2`. Then `print(sys.argv)` would show `['myscript.py', '-foobar', '2']`

Comment: This actually isn't a python question.  It's a shell question.  Add a tag for your shell (bash?  zsh?  other?).  I think you'll have to concatenate the values yourself regardless of the shell - a shell can't really set up 2 different stdin sources -  but let's see what others say.

Comment: Your use of select here is also kind of silly and nonsensical imho.  The code will work just fine without it.

Comment: Have you tried this : `echo foobar | { cat ; echo "test123"; } | python myscript.py`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible since both pipe and herestring use stdin, so one will always take precedence (the herestring).

As a workaround, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) `<()`. The script then needs to take a filename as an argument, e.g.:

```py
import sys

line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
print("Line from stdin:", line)

fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname) as f:
    line = f.readline().strip()
    print(f"Line from file ({fname}):", line)
```

```bash
$ ./tmp.py <(echo foobar) <<< "test123"
Line from stdin: test123
Line from file (/dev/fd/63): foobar
```

If you want to simplify, you can use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

```py
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.strip()
    print(f"Line from fileinput ({fileinput.filename()}):", line)
```

```bash
$ ./tmp.py - <(echo foobar) <<< "test123"
Line from fileinput (<stdin>): test123
Line from fileinput (/dev/fd/63): foobar
```

(stdin is specified as `-`.)